# Compare decimal places in numpy.where

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame, where I need to check row wise count of decimal places (with other condition) using in `numpy.where` and assign a value to a column: (Values are in string format)

[image]

Now  wherever the count of decimal is not 2 and value is not in between -100 to 200, then I have add a value saying 'issues' in a new column otherwise new column will be blank.

I don't want to use apply, want to use `numpy.where`.

Output:
[image]

Comment: please provide your input in a reproducible format, not an image

Comment: Also what is the expected output? None of your values have 2 significant decimal digits, did you mean non-zero digits? Are your values floats or strings?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Assuming `df` your DataFrame, [edit] your question with the output of `df.to_dict('list')`. Also read [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Values are in string format

Comment: *count of decimal is not 2 and value is not in between -100 to 200* - but `-0.11` has 2 decimal digits and is between -100 and 200. Why did you mark it "issue"?

Comment: `np.where(c,a,b)` is only as useful as the 3 arguments (arrays or Series)  `c`, the condition, has to be a Series that is true or false for each row of that frame - as a whole, not in an iterative sense.  `where` is a not an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

The exact logic is unclear as your description and example are not exactly matching, but for the general logic, assuming you want to flag values that are ending with 2 digits or not between -100-200, you can use [`pandas.to_numerid`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)+[`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and a regex with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)+[`str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
import numpy as np

# is the numeric value between -100 and 200?
m1 = pd.to_numeric(df['name2'], errors='coerce').between(-100, 200)
# is the count of the decimal not 2?
m2 = df['name2'].str.extract(r'\.(\d*[1-9]+)', expand=False).str.len().ne(2)

df['Error'] = np.where(m1&m2, 'No Issue', 'Issue')
```

Output:

```
  Name      name2     Error
0    A      0.029  No Issue
1    B          0  No Issue
2    V          2  No Issue
3    D  -0.000029  No Issue
4    E      -0.11     Issue
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': list('ABVDE'),
                   'name2': ['0.029', '0', '2', '-0.000029', '-0.11']
                  })
```

Intermediates:

```
  Name      name2    m1     m2  m1&m2     Error
0    A      0.029  True   True   True  No Issue
1    B          0  True   True   True  No Issue
2    V          2  True   True   True  No Issue
3    D  -0.000029  True   True   True  No Issue
4    E      -0.11  True  False  False     Issue
```

Answer (score 0):

This is using only `np.where` to get the answer you are asking. And code is easily readable.

```
cond = (df['name2'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[1].str.len() == 2) | (~df['name2'].between(-100, 200))
df['flag'] = np.where(cond, "issue", "no issue")

name     name2      flag
0    A  0.029000  no issue
1    B  0.000000  no issue
2    C  2.000000  no issue
3    D -0.000029  no issue
4    E -0.110000     issue
```